# AJAX not working in codeigniter to load page within same DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to develop simple CMS in codeigniter.. In main view there are several links to other pages but i want all the pages to open in the same view within a designated DIV without loading for every page( AJAX LOADING ). I tried to achieve this using AJAX  call but tired figuring it out why it is not working for me. Whenever i click on the link it just Load the view from the index method of the controller that is the LOGIN_VIEW.
Here is my cms view with the links

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function onLinkClick(value){
            alert('<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/load_view/'+value);
            $.ajax({    
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/load_view/', 
                type: 'POST',
                 data: {'view_param': value},
                 success: function(response)
                 {
                     //$('#mang_server').html(response);
                    alert("response recieved");
                 }
            }); 
            alert('after response');    
        }
</script>

<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="header"> <a href="" class="logo"><img src="../img/logo.gif" width="101" height="29" alt="" /></a>
        <div id="middle">
            <div id="left-column">
                <h3>Header</h3>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <?php foreach($ops as $operations)
                    {$op_name = $operations['admin_op'];
                     $op_link = $operations['link_to'];
                    ?>
                    <li><a href="" id="" onclick="onLinkClick('<?php echo $op_link ;?>')"><?php echo $op_name ;?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
                <div id="mang_server"> </div>
```

Both the alerts are working...But ajax call is messing up.

Here is my controller method

```
public function index()
{
  if($this->session->userdata('admin_name'!='')){
    $this->data['title'] = "Admin Area";
    $this->data['ops'] = $this->admin_model->get_admin_ops();
    $this->load->view('admin_view.php',$data);
  } else {
    $data['title'] = "Admin login";
    $this->load->view('admin_login.php',$data);
  }    
}

public function load_view($view_name)
{      
   $data['view_link'] = $this->admin_model->load_view_model($view_name);
   $this->load->view($data);
}
```

Please tell me what blunder i am making .

Comment: What do you mean by : But ajax call is messing up.

Comment: Try passing view name like $this->load->view($view_name,$data) in load_view function

Comment: means it is not working the way it should work.. it should load the view in the div(mang_Server) but it is loading the view which is specified in the index method of the controller.

Comment: @Nilesh but $view_name is the argument to the load_view method which simply takes the argument, pass it to the model,model fetches the name of the view from the database and return to the controller and then controller load the view named. why should i pass ($view_name) to the view.??

Comment: You have the typo error in this line if($this->session->userdata('admin_name')!=''){ the above code won't work

Comment: I didnt understand...please be more specific. @Sundar

Comment: $this->session->userdata('admin_name'!='') this syntax is proper or not please recheck it. This should be like this $this->session->userdata('admin_name')

Comment: But this isnt my issue... I need help related my question.Please

Comment: But $data['view_link'] = $this->admin_model->load_view_model($view_name); is only to fetch the link, this wil not load your desired view, in order to load the view , you need to pass the view name to   $this->load->view($data);

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in wrong way consider the following code for loading the view via ajax

Javascript part:

```
 $.ajax({

             url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/load_view/', 
             type: 'POST',
             dataType:'json',
             data: {'view_param': value},
             success: function(response)
             {

                $('#mang_server').html(response.html_view);

             }
 });
```

Admin controller:

```
public function load_view($view_name){

  $data['view_link'] = $this->admin_model->load_view_model($view_name);

  // IF $data['view_link'] is the name of the view file you are trying to load
  $response['html_view']$this->load->view($data['view_link'],'',TRUE);
  // While loading a view in codeigniter it accepts three parameters
  // $this->load->view("name of the view file","data to be passed to the view or not","Returning views as data");
 // For more refer at the end of the page http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Thanx @prathamesh...but can u please tell me why u put json as datatype.

Comment: Because we are returning json data from controller

Comment: hey @hasn-147 Please have a look at the edited part. Hope it makes your doubt clear.

Comment: thanks for your help...but i cant figure out why after click it goes to the view mentioned in the index method..